# Structure for Products table to store products details from various fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm building an application which requires supporting various categories of fields of products (as in products in Fashion, Electronics, Automobile, Grocery etc.), so obviously, for products in every field (& even for their sub-categories), product properties would vary from category to category.

**Example:**

Products in **Fashion** field, are like *Jeans, Shirts, etc.* which have properties like *size, color, type, material-type, etc.*, whereas Products in **Electronics**, can be like *Mobile phones, Laptops, etc.* which can have product properties like, *processor, memory, storage, size, color, etc.*

**My Question is in regarding, how do I store such information in most generalized & efficient way possible?**

**What I've thought of a solution:**

I've thought of creating **three** tables for maintaining this information.

1. **`products` table:**

This table will contain all products & their categories in **nested set form** such that **each parent** would act as a **category** and **each leaf** would act as a **product**.

Along with this, this table would contain meta information about the product (*like name, purchasing price, selling price, sku, etc. which would be common to any kind of product*). Probable **Table Structure** of this table is as under:

```
id(PK), 
client_fk(FK to clients), 
parent_id(for nested-sets), 
lft(for nested-sets), 
rgt(for nested-sets), 
depth(for nested-sets), 
name(meta), 
sku(meta), 
purchasing_price(meta), 
selling_price(meta), 
created_at, 
updated_at
```

2. Other two tables will kinda work like EAV model structure.

**`products_props`table:**

This table will store all possible properties to any product (from any category) like *size, color, processor, memory, storage, etc.* with **their meta details** like *description, input-type-details, etc.* **Table Structure** for this table can be

`id(PK), name, label, description, input_type, input_details, created_at, updated_at`

3. **`products_props_data` table**:

This table will contain values for all the properties that product have. **Table Structure** for this table can be:

`id(PK), product_prop_fk(FK to products_props), product_fk(FK to products), value, created_at, updated_at`

**Reads** on this information would be much more than ***inserts, updates or deletes***.

**Questions:**

1. Am I following the correct way?
2. Is it efficient?
3. Is there another way around?
4. Advises/suggestions to achieve what I am trying to.
5. How does well-known e-commerce do it? like Amazon, Flipkart, eBay?

Comment: You want to store your categories in the products table? There is no "correct way". But trying to reduce the number of tables is not a good one.

Comment: Yes, I am wishing to store categories in products table to reduce the number of tables so as to make things simple. With the correct way, I meant, theoretically, I don't want to re-invent things, what I mean is, if what I am trying is going towards dead-end or something problematic that already someone has suffered, and then why don't I take a help from that someone from his/her experience. Can you suggest better, simple and efficient way around?

Comment: If I do not store categoris in products table or if I do not use **nested-sets**, then I'll get limited to number categories I can have. And this is the requirement from the client to have any levels of categories.

Comment: Your solution looks good to me.  It partly resembles class table inheritance.  You may want to  research this buzzword to learn more,  but I think your current design adapts the technique already.

Comment: @nbh - "If I do not store categoris in products table or if I do not use nested-sets, then I'll get limited to number categories I can have" - Nothing in that sentence is true.

Comment: You would need to ask a clear question. This one is too broad and opinion based. You've touched two controverse subjects in one question: *EAV* and  *nested sets*.

Comment: This indeed IS ACTUALLY the clear question, I mean, I depicted the problem that I am facing and the solution which I have been thinking to give a go. What I wanted to know is, is this how applications in this field made, have I thought about correct table structure, If not, what are the other ways? Because, If this is not the correct **foundation** that I am building then the whole application is going to fail drastically. While writing the question, I did realize, it may turn into an opinion based, but I thought providing what I've thought for the soln is also important.

Comment: I couldn't find any other better solution without _EAV_ and _nested-sets_, both seemed to be an essential part for the solution... This may be because of my limited knowledge & experience. **I would really like to improve the question to make it more clear**, to obtain the answers, can you help me to do it? I understand the question is broad, but this is the foundation of an application I am talking about.

Comment: Nested sets are adapted towards a lot of reads and few writes.  EAV is adapted towards very generalaized with Iittle analysis?  These seem to me to be pulling in opposite directions.  Just my opinion

Comment: What do you ntend to do with the EAV data?

Comment: Just for reading purpose. The application is more about Stock & Order Management, so the product details are just for reading purposes. Product Details data within EAV can be used to identify/search product.

Comment: The core objective of Application is the analysis of Stock within the Store & Orders (May it be pending, purchasing, selling). I've decided to keep such core data separate from EAV, Like, for stocks of product, I'm thinking to maintain a separate table for it, with structure: `id(PK), product_fk(FK to products), stock, created_at, updated_at`. And there are separate sets of tables for orders.

Answer (score 1):

1. Seems ok
2. Don't worry about this just yet
3. Probably
4. If using an EAV, I like to construct different tables for different kinds of attribute types - so, I'll have a table for integer attributes, a table for decimal attributes, and a table for strings

Comment: 4. I didn't think for a different table for different attributes, to make it less complex. I didn't find benefits of going that complex, can you help me learn that?

Comment: The point is that you can take advantage of datatypes, which in turn can aid performance-otherwise you're obliged to store everything as if it's a string (or have thousands of nulls)